# add char to every tuple second element in list

Tags: haskell, recursion

```
getNames 'A' [('A', "Smith"), ('J', "Brown")] -> ["A.Smith", "A.Brown"]
```

I try to add just char to every string element in list. My code is:

```
addForEvery :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
addForEvery a (x:xs) = [a] ++ x : addForEvery a xs
print(addForEvery 'a' ["fa"])
```

But I get the following error:

```
jdoodle.hs:6:32: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [String]
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x : addForEvery a xs’
      In the expression: [a] ++ x : addForEvery a xs
      In the expression: [[a] ++ x : addForEvery a xs]
  |
6 | addForEvery a (x:xs) = [[a] ++ x : addForEvery a xs]
  |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In your example, how does `"Smith"` turn into `"Taylor"`?

Comment: The signature is already inconsistent: in your example, the second argument is a list of pairs, but in your signature `addForEvery :: Char -> [String] -> [String]`, the second argument is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it!

```
getNames :: Char -> [(Char, String)] -> [String]
getNames a [] = []
getNames a ((z, b):xs) = ([a] ++ ['.'] ++ b) : getNames a xs
```

Comment: Or `(a : '.' : b)` instead of `[a] ++ ['.'] ++ b`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `[a] ++ x : addForEvery a xs` is interpreted as `[a] ++ (x : addForEvery a xs)`. This makes not much sense since `[a]` is a `String`, it expects `x : addForEvery a xs`, but that is a list of `String`s.

You can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to apply the same function to all items in the list. We thus can implement this as:

```
getNames :: [(Char, String)] -> [String]
getNames = map toFullName
    where toFullName fn ln = fn : '.' : ln
```